# Sending GAE email from a custom domain

Tags: email, google-app-engine

Is it possible for GAE to send emails from a domain other than appspotmail.com?

I currently have a GAE project pointing to a domain name hosted by GoDaddy. I was not able to do something like this:

```
mail.EmailMessage(sender='John Doe <no-reply@my-custom-domain.com',
```

This errored out, saying this was an invalid sender. Not a big surprise.

Is it possible to use my custom domain?

Comment: Check requirements at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#who_can_send_mail. I was able to use my custom domain email addresses after adding them to the Email API Authorized Senders in my app's settings, but my custom domain (hosted by ENOM) was purchased through Google, not sure if the same will work w/ GoDaddy. It's worth a try.

Comment: Ah! I missed that "authorized sender" option. That must be it. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work with GoDaddy. Just tried it and got "unauthorized sender". Also found this in the docs: "All email addresses on the Email API Authorized Senders list need to be valid Gmail or Google-hosted domain accounts."

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but maybe you can use third party senders (app engine docs mention Sendgrid, Mailjet, and Mailgun).  This is what I do on my own project (though not with the three aforementioned ones), since my needs exceed those offered by appengine's mail quotas. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail